# Are regression CIs valid when the outcome is an ML prediction?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, inference

If we use classification labels from a machine learning model in a linear regression, and treat those labels as the ground truth, will the resulting confidence intervals be valid?

Imagine we have $n$ labelled (ground truth) points and a larger set of $N$ unlabelled points.

1. We train a machine learning model on the $n$ labelled points and use it to generate labels for the $N$ unlabelled points.
2. We then group the $n+N$ points together and regress their labels on some random treatment indicator $X$ with the goal of estimating the causal effect of $X$ on the label.
3. We construct confidence intervals for this regression, treating the labels as ground truth.

My question is, will the resulting confidence intervals be valid? My intuition is that they will be too small, but I can't prove it.

Comment: You're right, those intervals will in general be too tight! You've got to find some way of accounting for the uncertainty in the ML model's outputs. One approach to this is bootstrapping: randomly subset your data, fit your ML model, then fit your linear regression, get a prediction, and repeat. Means you'd have to fit your ML models many times though, which can be trouble if they're already computationally intensive.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! While this is not the same as a formal proof, simulation is a great tool to get a feel for how this works. My recommendation is to code it up and see how often your confidence intervals contain the true parameters.

Comment: Thanks John and Dave. I'm quite convinced this is true but am trying to work out exactly how to prove it. Maybe another way to frame this question is, how does the prediction uncertainty fit into the formula for the uncertainty of the estimates?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple version of this is 'regression calibration' as used in measurement error models in epidemiology.  In that setting you definitely do need to handle the standard errors separately: there is error of order $O_p(n^{-1/2})$ from the small labelled set and error of order $O_p( (N+n)^{-1/2})$ from the final fit. It's quite likely that the first error term dominates.

Resampling does work: you resample from the $n$ and refit your machine-learning model, then resample from the $N$ and refit your treatment model. Stratifying the resampling this way ensures that $n$ and $N$ stay fixed in the resamples. (The bootstrap tends to be slightly conservative in this setting and people often use a sandwich estimator instead).  Here's [an example](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8245895/)

Answer (score 0):

The measurement error at issue here is an error in the dependent variable in the linear model. I believe the 'labels minus ground truth' could be considered 'classical measurement error'; orthogonal (independent?) of the right-hand-side variables.

Paraphrasing Greene (Econometric Analysis 1993, page 280-8), and similar points in other sources (Wikipedia, https://theeffectbook.net/ etc.) in the image below (my notes are linked here):

[image: maths pasted in of the CLM with measurement error in the outcome]

Such an estimate should be unbiased. Furthermore, while the measurement error in the outcome variable is indeed adding noise, this noise is incorporated in our calculation of the standard errors. While this reduces our statistical power relative to to a case without measurement error, it does not lead us to be falsely confident, so our p-values etc. are correctly stated. We should have correct 'coverage' I think.

(However, this might be an asymptotic result only.)